# Enlarge video using WPF MediaElement

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to expand the MediaElement to watch larger videos, but the problem is I can not do it in any way, I do it manually in the designer and does not work, well I try manually with min-height and min-width property but the video remains the same size.

By "expand" I mean that I want the video to fill the `MediaElement`. Right now it is very small.

Source :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1028" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Height="512" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="player" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" MinHeight="800" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,566,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: expand the MediaElement to see more long videos on the form

Comment: i say width , no length

Comment: they look like small video, I try to enlarge the MediaElement but the video always looks just as small.

Comment: I believe you just need to set the `Stretch` property to `Fill`, could you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your content to fill the `MediaElement` area, set the `Stretch` property to "Fill":

```
<MediaElement Stretch="Fill" .../>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information and other valid values of this property.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and support